# Sql data filtering

Tags: sql

I am begginer to sql , need a help, how can i segregate the marks of a student only when the pass flag is Y . currently  for learning purpose , i have created a table and added 3 columns with two Y flag and one N flag. The query should only return sum of mark only when all the flag is Y.
[image]

Can someone help .

Thanks,

Comment: `select sum(marks) from learn where pass='Y'`

Comment: actually the last record also beling to xxx

Comment: only we need to calculate the sum of marks only when pass is Y . how can we achive that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `HAVING` clause and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name,
       SUM(marks)
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN pass = 'N' THEN 1 END) = 0
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  name  VARCHAR(10),
  marks NUMERIC,
  pass  VARCHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO table_name (name, marks, pass)
SELECT 'xxx', 50, 'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx', 50, 'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 'zzz', 50, 'N';
```

Outputs the "sum of mark only when all the flag is Y.":

> | name | SUM(marks) |
> | --- | --- |
> | xxx | 100 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c506c29de80274221cbd1e34990ad2fa)*

Comment: INSERT INTO table_name (name, marks, pass)
SELECT 'xxx', 50, 'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx', 50, 'Y' UNION ALL
SELECT 'xxx', 50, 'N';

Comment: i need to only fetch when all there records pass flag is Y

Comment: @Sidh That is what the `HAVING` clause is there to do, exclude the group when not all of the rows' pass flags are `Y`.

Comment: Bit confused wil was checking on another data set

Comment: The having clause is not working as expected

Comment: @Sidh Stating "is not working as expected" is not a constructive statement as it does not tell us why you think it is not as expect nor does it tell us what the expected should be. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72793572/edit) your question to include details of what your expected answer would be and explain why it is like that.

Comment: sure  MTO i wil update the question

Comment: Why do you need `having`? Why not use `where`?

Comment: @Shmiel Because the OP wants the groups where ALL the rows are `Y` and not the groups where only some of the rows are `Y`.